# Concurrent write on different table in the same db with python

Tags: python, database, multithreading

i'm writing a python script that fetches data from a site and saves it in a sqlite db table. Having a very high amount of data, I was thinking of reducing the extraction times by entrusting the extraction to 2 threads. I tried with two threads that write on different databases, here my question arises: is it possible to write in the same database but in different tables? (in the same table ??)

I thought of some approaches that I don't know if they are feasible:

1) use a db that uses contemporary writes (mysql? / Postgre?)

2) write the data in two different tables of two different databases and merge them at the end of extraction (possible?)

3) write the data from the two threads on a dummy table and merge them a fine extraction in a real table (possible?)

I don't know if anyone is in this situation, I am open to any suggestions.

thank you!

Comment: It's possible; each thread can use a different connection, and commit its updates in separate transactions.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I have two threads that take different data and write it directly into the table. Do you mean that maybe I can write data in different arrays and write them at the end of the extraction on the db consecutively? similar to point 3.

Comment: Option 1 should work, unless you need to do additional preprocessing before writing to the destination table.  Databases are designed to handle concurrent updates.  You'll only have problems if there are integrity violations, for example if two threads try to write the same value to a column that has a unique constraint.

Comment: @snakecharmerb if i don't have this limitation, how can i proceed to run option 1?